# Java sets: why there is no T get(Object o)?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the java.util.Set<V> interface not provide a get(Object o) method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861296/why-does-the-java-util-setv-interface-not-provide-a-getobject-o-method)

Why Java sets don't have methods for retrieving an element that is equal to provided?

For example, I need to create an object pool, something like String.intern() method (yes, I know that this is usually done with weak references), so I need to create a Map and do map.put(o,o) to put my unique object if they are not present in the map. But a set is more appropriate in this case I think.

Comment: Sorry, missed out that there was the same question. What is the best thing to do: leave as is, or delete it?

Comment: Can you vote to close your question as a duplicate?