# BlackJack Program, string value issue

Tags: java, blackjack, gambling

I'm in the midst of creating a BlackJack program. I'm currently in the "number checking" process. So once the cards have been dealt and the player asks for a "Hit" I need to check if the cards they have exceed, 21. 
I tried this :

```
if(pCard1+pCard2+pCard3 > 21)
    System.out.println("Bust!");
```

But it soon came to my realization that because my card array is an array of strings, I cannot use mathematical operators to check wether or not the cards exceed 21. I was wondering if there was anyway to assign a Int value to each of my strings so that I can check mathematically wether or not they exceed 21.

```
    else if(game == 3) {
 int bet = 0;
 String HoS;
 ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList<String>();
 cards.add("1");
 cards.add("2");
 cards.add("3");
 cards.add("4");
 cards.add("5");
 cards.add("6");
 cards.add("7");
 cards.add("8");
 cards.add("9");
 cards.add("10");
 cards.add("Jack");
 cards.add("Queen");
 cards.add("King");
 cards.add("Ace");

 System.out.println("------------------BLACKJACK---------------------");
 System.out.println("Welcome to BlackJack!");
 System.out.println("Current balance $"+balance);
 System.out.print("How much would you like to bet on this hand?:");
    bet = input.nextInt();
 System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------");
 System.out.println("Dealing cards.........");

 Random card = new Random();
 String pCard1 = cards.get(card.nextInt(cards.size()));
 String pCard2 = cards.get(card.nextInt(cards.size()));

 System.out.println("Your hand is a "+pCard1+","+pCard2);
 System.out.print("Would you like hit or stand?:");
    HoS = input.next();
if(HoS.equals("Hit")) {
    String pCard3 = cards.get(card.nextInt(cards.size()));
        System.out.print("*Dealer Hits* The card is "+pCard3);
    }
else if(HoS.equals("Stand")) {
    System.out.println("Dealing Dealer's hand........");
    String dCard1 = cards.get(card.nextInt(cards.size()));
    String dCard2 = cards.get(card.nextInt(cards.size()));
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions/advice.

Comment: Instead of an Array of strings, how about a dictionary/hash table where the key is an int and the value is a string?

Comment: could you explain? Never heard of that.

Comment: You can do : `Map<Int, String> dictionary = new HashMap<Int, String>();` Then add each item: `dictionary.put(1, "Ace");`

Comment: Ok, implemented this but It's telling me that Map and HashMap cannot be resolved to a type. Must Import something to use this?

Comment: `import java.util.Map;` and `import java.util.HashMap;`

Comment: If you are just starting out, I would recommend something like IntelliJ IDE so you can get auto-complete help and suggestions for things like missing imports, etc. They have a free community version: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Will check that out. Thank you very much for your help, it's working now.

Comment: Cool, I'll post as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JacobIRR said in his comment you can use `Map` but I would recommend you to use the key as a `String` (The card name) and the value as `Integer` (the value of the card).

Remember you can not give `Map` `int` as a Key, it has to be `Integer` (You cannot use primitive types in `Map`)

It will be like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> cards = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

and put all your cards like this:

```
cards.put("1", 1);
cards.put("2", 2);
...
cards.put("Jack", 11);
cards.put("Queen", 12);
cards.put("King", 13);
cards.put("Ace", 1);
```

Then your `if condition` will be like this:

```
if(cards.get(pCard1) + cards.get(pCard2) +cards.get(pCard3) > 21)
    System.out.println("Bust!");
```

Comment: I did this, but it seems to have messed with my random card grabbing method.                                                                                             
  String pCard1 = cards.get(cards.nextInt(cards.size()));                       
 No longer works since it's a string now.

Comment: You can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385392/4780434
get Array of all the keyset and put the random card grabbing method in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
Map<Int, String> dictionary = new HashMap<Int, String>();
```

Then add each item:

```
dictionary.put(1, "Ace");
```