# Method return type error

Tags: java, switch-statement, blackjack

I'm using a method to deal a card in my Black Jack program. This is my method:

```
 public static String dealCard() {
    Random randomCard = new Random();
    int min = 1;
    int rCard = min + randomCard.nextInt(13);
    switch(rCard) {
    case 1 : return "2"; 
    case 2 : return "3";
    case 3 : return "4";
    case 4 : return "5";
    case 5 : return "6";
    case 6 : return "7";
    case 7 : return "8";
    case 8 : return "9";
    case 9 : return "10";
    case 10 : return "Queen";
    case 11 : return "Jack";
    case 12 : return "King";
    case 13 : return "Ace";
    }
 }
```

However I'm getting the following error...

`This method must return a result of type String.`

Which is why I'm confused because aren't I returning a string when I pick the case and then it returns the card? I'm quite confused. I tried switching my method around and trying to do it with If statements instead of a switch case, but I'm still getting the same method. I suspected that it was part of my `nextInt();` function but I couldn't figure out what. I'd appreciate any suggestion on where I might be going wrong.

Comment: What if rCard = 20? (The compiler doesn't know that this isn't possible) - what does your method return then?

Comment: Nothing to do with the actual question:I don't do Java but doesn't randomCard.nextInt(13) mean the random number is upper bound to 13 (12 + 1)? A result of 20 shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Steve The **compiler** doesn't know that. That's the point of the comment

Comment: Additionally, this is exactly the kind of case where a `Map` is called for, or even just an array of strings.

Comment: Unrelated to the original problem but I want to ask, shouldn't Jack come before Queen? Oh maybe you were thinking "ladies first" :-P

Comment: Not entirely sure why you're not using suggestions from your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49714583/assigning-int-value-to-string   or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591418/blackjack-program-string-value-issue

Answer (score 1):

Add a `default:` to your `switch` statement:

```
public static String dealCard() {
    Random randomCard = new Random();
    int min = 1;
    int rCard = min + randomCard.nextInt(12);
    String cardDealt = "";
    switch (rCard) {
        case 1:
            cardDealt = "Ace";
            break;
        case 2:case 3:case 4:case 5:case 6:case 7:case 8:case 9:
            cardDealt = Integer.toString(rCard);
            break;
        case 10:
            cardDealt = "Jack";
            break;
        case 11:
            cardDealt = "Queen";
            break;
        case 12:
            cardDealt = "King";
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("rCard unexpectedly out of range");
    }
    return cardDealt;
}
```

Comment: Although you and I know it will never get used, the compiler isn't clever enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to return values outside of the possible cases.

Also, while a simple if-else would look cleaner, you can use a fall through case statement

```
switch(rCard) {
    case 10 : return "Queen";
    case 11 : return "Jack";
    case 12 : return "King";
    case 13 : return "Ace";
    case 1 :
    case 2 :
    case 3 : 
    case 4 : 
    case 5 : 
    case 6 : 
    case 7 : 
    case 8 : 
    case 9 : return String.valueOf(rCard + 1);
    default: return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't be certain that one of your `case` statements will be hit and thus you will `return` a value. There **must** be a value returned. You could add a `default` case to the `switch`. Or, just move your last `return` to the last statement. Also, it's a bad idea to re-initialize your `Random` on every invocation. In a loop, you ***might*** get the same seed.

```
private static Random randomCard = new Random();
private static final int MIN = 1; // <-- this is a CONSTANT
private static final int MAX = 13; // <-- this is a CONSTANT
public static String dealCard() {
    int rCard = MIN + randomCard.nextInt(MAX);
    switch(rCard) {
    case 1 : return "2"; 
    case 2 : return "3";
    case 3 : return "4";
    case 4 : return "5";
    case 5 : return "6";
    case 6 : return "7";
    case 7 : return "8";
    case 8 : return "9";
    case 9 : return "10";
    case 10 : return "Queen";
    case 11 : return "Jack";
    case 12 : return "King";
    }
    return "Ace";
}
```

You ***could*** optimize it a little further (imo) with a `Map` and `getOrDefault` like

```
private static Random randomCard = new Random();
private static final int MIN = 1; // <-- this is a CONSTANT
private static final int MAX = 13; // <-- this is a CONSTANT
private static final Map<Integer, String> faceCards = new HashMap<>();
static {
    faceCards.put(11, "Jack");
    faceCards.put(10, "Queen");
    faceCards.put(12, "King");
    faceCards.put(13, "Ace");
}

public static String dealCard() {
    int rCard = MIN + randomCard.nextInt(MAX);
    return faceCards.getOrDefault(rCard, String.valueOf(rCard + 1));
}
```

Comment: Off topic - is using static blocks to initialize a constant map considered good practice?

Comment: @cricket_007 Having globals (at all) is generally not considered a best practice. Here I'm initializing a `private static` field. The next logical place to do this would be an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

This code cannot be compiled, because you missed a return statement if rCard will be less than 1 or more than 13.
You have 2 options to resolve this:

- add a default option in switch
- throw an IllegalStateException in the end of method

So, the final code should be look like this:

```
public static String dealCard() {
    Random randomCard = new Random();
    int min = 1;
    int rCard = min + randomCard.nextInt(13);
    switch(rCard) {
        case 1 : return "2";
        case 2 : return "3";
        case 3 : return "4";
        case 4 : return "5";
        case 5 : return "6";
        case 6 : return "7";
        case 7 : return "8";
        case 8 : return "9";
        case 9 : return "10";
        case 10 : return "Queen";
        case 11 : return "Jack";
        case 12 : return "King";
        case 13 : return "Ace";
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("No return value fo case " + rCard);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More an elegant and optimized way using enums:

```
 public enum Card {
    TWO(2, "2"),
    THREE(3, "3"),
    FOUR(4, "4"),
    FIVE(5, "5"),
    SIX(6, "6"),
    SEVEN(7, "7"),
    EIGHT(8, "8"),
    NINE(9, "9"),
    TEN(10, "10"),
    QUEEN(11, "Queen"),
    JACK(12, "Jack"),
    KING(13, "King"),
    ACE(14, "Ace");

    private final int value;
    private final String name;

    private static final Card[] VALUES = values();
    private static final int SIZE = VALUES.length;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    Card(int value, String name) {
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Card getRandomCard() {
        return VALUES[RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE)];
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Card.getRandomCard().getName());
}
```