# Using a Set with one Class but find with a String

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I have a Java `Set<MyClass>` on which I've overridden `equals` and `hashCode` to use the `String name;` variable.

```
public class MyClass{
    final String name;
    public boolean equals(Object o){...}
    public int hashCode(){return name.hashCode();}
}
```

Is there anyway I can get my Object out of the HashSet using something like

```
MyClass o = set.get("nameofmyobject");
```

Is there a way to do this in Java, or a datastructure? or do I need to change up all of my Sets to Maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861296/why-does-the-java-util-setv-interface-not-provide-a-getobject-o-method) question. The answer is no. `Set`s are not for getting elements, but to look for equality. Use a `Map` or `List` insteed.

Comment: A list gives `O(n)` access. Might as well just iterate through the set.

Comment: I like the link to that question. I hadn't seen that.  Even that question doesn't really explain why though :(

Comment: If you look up in a Set for an Object you have the Object already, otherwise you couldn't find it i guess. So why not working with the Object after the equality check?

Comment: Notice my question, I don't have the Object, I just have `key` that represents equality for the object

Answer (score 3):

No. You need to change to a `Map`. None of the methods of `Set` return an element.

**Addendum A**
If you don't care about speed you can always search manually:

```
MyClass find(String name, Set<MyClass> set)
{
    MyClass wrapper = new MyClass(name);
    for (MyClass e : set) {
        if (wrapper.equals(e)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Addendum B**
If you use a `TreeSet` you can use `floor`:

```
MyClass find(String name, TreeSet<MyClass> set)
{
    MyClass wrapper = new MyClass(name);
    MyClass candidate = set.floor(wrapper);
    if (candidate != null && wrapper.equals(candidate)) {
        return candidate;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do care about speed, which is why I'm using set, and will now have to move to a Map.  I'm just not happy about increasing the Space requirements by `O(n)` to store (what seems to me) redundant keys

Comment: @JaySmith It won't use any more space. Java's `HashSet` is implemented using a `HashMap`. See the [JDK7 source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/2d/jdk/file/8f19b165347b/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java).

Comment: Thanks for the link tom, never knew that

Answer (score 1):

As Tim said you can't. And if so you would have to call it like set.get(myClassInstance); and not set.get(some member of the stored instance)

Use

```
   Map<String, MyClass> myMap = new HashMap<String, MyClass>();
```